# Is it okay to set instance variables in a Django class based view?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I trying out Django's class based views (CBVs).

```
class BlahView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blah/blah.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #code...

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        #more code...
```

Now, I know that I can get the request params from self.request. Now say I want to parse these request params and store them within the class. Can I store those in `self.xxx`? Now, obviously based on how classes work, this seems straightforward.

But I can't make out the flow of control, looking at the definition of `View` (superclass of `TemplateView`). The [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py) mentions `as_view()` to be the 'entry-point'

I thought of setting my instance variables at the beginning of `get_context_data()` but that doesn't seem right to do initialization there.

Can I define an `__init__()` for my CBV?
If so, will there be threading issues or something where multiple page-accesses possibly work with a global instance of my parsed data?

I know this sounds a bit messy, but I'm just a bit confused with the code flow in CBVs.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

According to [the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/views/generic/base.py#L28) of `django.views.generic.base.View.as_view`:

- **on django startup**, as_view() returns a function `view`, which is **not** called
- **on request**, `view()` **is called**, it instantiates the class and calls `dispatch()`
- the class instance is thread safe

According to [the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/views/generic/base.py#L17) of `django.views.generic.base.View.__init__`, the request object is out of scope at this point so you can't parse it in your own constructor overload.

However, you could parse the request and set class view instance attributes in an overload of `django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch`, this is safe according to the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/views/generic/base.py#L57):

```
class YourView(SomeView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # parse the request here ie.
        self.foo = request.GET.get('foo', False)

        # call the view
        return super(YourView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the event run-through :) It seems a bit yucky to do initialization anywhere other than an __init__... and it might seem a bit weird when others will work on my code, but I guess CBV design forces our hand.

Comment: Note that the [Django CBV docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#generic-views) explicitly say that storing state variables on the instance is thread safe, so we're not just relying on our reading of the source code.

Comment: It doesn't force your hand: you could override as_view() and change the wrapper logic, so that it pass request to __init__.

Comment: @Alasdair: Damn! How did I miss that! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It might be a better idea to use `kwargs` instead of `GET` as you can get anything in GET, and kwargs are filtered by regular expressions.

Comment: I think it is still ok to initialize something in ctor, like self.object = None in the view that has SingleObjectMixin

Comment: also by: `kwargs.get("foo", "foo_default")`

Answer (score 2):

@jpic provided a great answer. Inspired from it, I would like to reference the following [blog post](http://andrewsforge.com/article/overcoming-troubles-with-class-based-views/) where the author claims that:

> ... We cannot override view, as doing so would require overriding
>   as_view(). Overriding dispatch() is appealing (and what I did
>   originally when I presented this talk) because it offers a single
>   simple place to do so, but this defies the logic of dispatch().
>   Instead, it is best to call set_account() in overrides of both get()
>   and post(). ...

Therefore, one can override the `get` or `post` methods and set any `self.whatever` variables. It feels somehow cleaner.