# URL-parameters and logic in Django class-based views (TemplateView)

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

It is unclear to me how it is best to access URL-parameters in class-based-views in Django 1.5.

Consider the following:

**View:**

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView


class Yearly(TemplateView):
    template_name = "calendars/yearly.html"

    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Yearly, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_year'] = self.current_year
        context['current_month'] = self.current_month
        return context
```

**URLCONF:**

```
from .views import Yearly


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<year>\d+)/$',
        view=Yearly.as_view(),
        name='yearly-view'
    ),
)
```

I want to access the `year` parameter in my view, so I can do logic like:

```
month_names = [
    "January", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", "July", "August", 
    "September", "October", "November", "December"
]

for month, month_name in enumerate(month_names, start=1):
    is_current = False
    if year == current_year and month == current_month:
        is_current = True
        months.append({
            'month': month,
            'name': month_name,
            'is_current': is_current
        })
```

How would one best access the url parameter in CBVs like the above that is subclassed of `TemplateView` and where should one ideally place the logic like this, eg. in a method?

Comment: There is the option of the simple `extra_context` dict in `django2`, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/)

Answer (score 152):

To access the url parameters in class based views, use `self.args` or `self.kwargs` so you would access it by doing `self.kwargs['year']`

Comment: Is it correctly understood that I'm not supposed to create variables directly in the view like I have above? (something about them being persistent). Also I don't understand where I'm supposed to place logic like the above, eg. in which method? Also when I do `year = self.kwargs['year']` in the view I get `NameError: self not defined`.

Comment: Technically you shouldn't since they are at the class level and are class variables. As for the `NameError`, where are you trying to do `year = self.kwargs['year']`? You should be doing it in a method, you can't do it at the class level. So for example, you are using a `TemplateView` which means that you would do the logic in your `get_context_data` override.

Comment: Just for referencing: The documentation on self.request, self.args etc can be found in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: Also you can do it in `def __init__(self):` function in the class if you want to access it outside other functions.

Answer (score 83):

In case you pass URL parameter like this:

```
http://<my_url>/?order_by=created
```

You can access it in class based view by using `self.request.GET` (its not presented in `self.args` nor in `self.kwargs`):

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class MyClassBasedView(ListView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by') or '-created'
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.order_by(order_by)
```

Comment: Thanks! This has been confusing me... I keep reading stuff that implies HTTP parameters will be in the kwargs.

Comment: Can you show the get_queryset() of the superclass of MyClassBasedView? I would just do  `qs=<Object>.objects.<method>`

Answer (score 28):

I found this elegant solution, and for django 1.5 or higher, as pointed out [here](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html):

> Django’s generic class based views now automatically include a view
>   variable in the context. This variable points at your view object.

In your views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView    

class Yearly(TemplateView):
    template_name = "calendars/yearly.html"
    # Not here 
    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month

    # dispatch is called when the class instance loads
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.year = kwargs.get('year', "any_default")

    # other code

    # needed to have an HttpResponse
    return super(Yearly, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The dispatch solution found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11448882/5476782).
As the [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/) is already passed within Template context, you don't really need to worry about it. In your template file yearly.html, it is possible to access those view attributes simply by:

```
{{ view.year }}
{{ view.current_year }}
{{ view.current_month }}
```

You can **keep your urlconf** as it is.

It's worth mentioning that getting information into your template’s context overwrites the get_context_data(), so it is somehow breaking the django's *action bean* flow.

Answer (score 15):

How about just use Python decorators to make this intelligible:

```
class Yearly(TemplateView):

    @property
    def year(self):
       return self.kwargs['year']
```

Comment: I like this one. The property is reusable.

Answer (score 8):

So far I've only been able to access these url parameters from within the get_queryset method, although I've only tried it with a ListView not a TemplateView. I'll use the url param to create an attribute on the object instance, then use that attribute in get_context_data to populate the context:

```
class Yearly(TemplateView):
    template_name = "calendars/yearly.html"

    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.year = self.kwargs['year']
        queryset = super(Yearly, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Yearly, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_year'] = self.current_year
        context['current_month'] = self.current_month
        context['year'] = self.year
        return context
```

Comment: I find that odd, is there an error or something when you try to do `context['year'] = self.kwargs['year']`? It should be accessible anywhere in the class.

Comment: @Ngenator: I just set up a clean django project to double check and it turns out you are correct. I'm not sure what was preventing this in my original code but I'll find out :).  Thanks for the heads-up