# using querydict item for if-statement

Tags: django, django-templates

The url: `myurl/?page=1&reverse`

Now I want to check in the template whether `reverse` is in there:

```
{% if request.GET.reverse %}
  do somthing
{% endif %}
```

But what's in between of `if` and `endif` never happens!

What should I use instead of `request.GET.reverse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put that logic inside your `view`? Like this:

```
# Function Based View (FBV)

def my_view(request):
    reversed = request.GET.get('reverse', '')
    return render(request, 'template.html', locals())

# Class Based View (CBV)
class MyView(ListView):
    template_name = 'path/to/template.html'
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
    context_object_name = 'my_obj'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['reversed'] = self.request.GET.get('reverse', '')
        return context
```

Then do:

```
{% if reversed %}
    do somthing
{% endif %}
```

On the other hand, if you still want to do this kind of logic in your template then you should create your [own filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/) like this:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()    

def is_in_dict(d, key):
    return key in d
```

and use it like this:

```
{% load my_filters %}

{% if request.GET|is_in_dict:"reverse" %}
    do somthing
{% endif %}
```

Comment: How does that work with generic views? (I am using a ListView.) Adding a variable `reversed` to context?

Comment: The value of `reversed` in this case would be falsey, since it's an empty string, even if the key exists. It would be better to use something like this:  `reversed = 'reverse' in request.GET`

Comment: @Asqiir Answers to this question explains how to do this with a class based view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754122/url-parameters-and-logic-in-django-class-based-views-templateview

Comment: @Asqiir. Yes, Haken Lid is right. Check out this link to see how to do it with CBV.