# send value from anchor tag to views

Tags: django, django-models

i have blog field in my project. i want to send the post id in to the views.py
tell me what i'm doing wrong

in blog.html

```
<a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read 
more</a>
```

in urls:

```
path('post_detail/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post- 
detail')
```

in views:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    search = self.request.GET.get('pk')
    if search:
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(page_id=search)
        print(queryset)

    else:
        return queryset.none()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL-parameters and logic in Django class-based views (TemplateView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754122/url-parameters-and-logic-in-django-class-based-views-templateview)

Comment: `DetailView` has no `get_queryset` (I believe).  `DetailView` has `get_object`

Comment: But you don't actually need to define any methods here at all. Getting the object from the parameter is what the DetailView fits for you already.

Comment: just have reference of [Django class-based-view](https://ccbv.co.uk/) for class based view in django it is very helpful. you can access url arguments in views as `self.kwargs['pk']`.

Answer (score 2):

add the template properties and it will work.

```
template_name = 'app-name-template/single_post.html'
```

also queryset it your case is not needed so remove it.

Comment: thanks for your response.. Instead of queryset what to write

Comment: can you write code for this.. template_name= ''prodcutSearch/post_detail.html'

Comment: i don't know how to write code using template_name..i just want blog's id..so i can use it with comment

Comment: if my solution worked for you please accept it as solution for your answer :)