# Django: test TemplateView based views triggered by url pattern?

Tags: python, django, testing

Say I have the following **url**

```py
path('clients/by_<str:order>', BrowseClients.as_view(), name='browse_clients')
```

and its corresponding **view**

```py
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BrowseClients(TemplateView):

    template_name = "console/browse_clients.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['clients'] = Client.objects.filter(
            owner=self.request.user.id).order_by(self.kwargs["order"])
        context['form'] = AddClientForm()
        return context
```

How can I **test** what is in the `context`?

```py
class TestBrowseClientsView(TestCase, GeneralViewTest):
    fixtures = ['users.yaml', 'clients.yaml']

    def setUp(self):
        self.request = RequestFactory().get('/console/clients/by_inscription')
        self.request.user = User.objects.get(pk=1)

    def test_return_client_ordered_by_inscription_date(self): 
        view = BrowseClients()
        view.setup(self.request)
        context = view.get_context_data()
```

Naively, I thought that `view.setup(self.request)` would "*feed*" `.get_context_data()` with the relevant `kwargs` based on the pattern found in `self.request`. But it does not seem to be the case.

```sh
======================================================================
ERROR: test_return_client_ordered_by_inscription_date (console.tests.TestBrowseClientsView)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/jengu/console/tests.py", line 164, in test_return_client_ordered_by_inscription_date
    context = view.get_context_data()
  File "/usr/src/jengu/console/views.py", line 34, in get_context_data
    owner=self.request.user.id).order_by(self.kwargs["order"])
KeyError: 'order'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why is that the case? I managed to fix my problem by passing `status` and `order` explicitly but it looks a bit *ad hoc*:

```py
def get_context_data(self, status, order, **kwargs):
```

```py
    def test_return_clients_ordered_by_parameter(self): 
        view = BrowseClients()
        view.setup(self.request)
        context = view.get_context_data("all", "inscription")
```

Among the [different options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754122/url-parameters-and-logic-in-django-class-based-views-templateview) mentioned here, which one is the more canonical? Am I taking a wrong path, explicitly using variables when defining `get_context_data()`?

Comment: Not really an answer, but you should pass the ordering field via the querystring (ie "/console/clients/?by=inscription"), not as part of the url path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [the test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) it will take care of running middleware and initialising the view.

When you use `setup()` and call the view directly, the URL handler does not run, so it's up to you to pass the kwargs.

```
def test_return_client_ordered_by_inscription_date(self): 
    view = BrowseClients()
    view.setup(self.request, order='inscription')
    context = view.get_context_data()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check what will be in the context of a response, first you need to work with a response object (and you are not, you are just making an instance of your view, not getting the response generated by the view). I don't know about `RequestFactory`, but I'm sure you'll find out how to adapt my answer to your use case.

So, it would be something like:

```py
def test_your_context(self):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
    self.client.force_login(user) # because of the login_required decorator
    response = self.client.get(reverse("browse_clients"))
    assert response.context['your_context_key'] == "Anything you want to check"
```

Just a few things to go further:

- the definition of your `get_context_data` method seems ok to me,
- if you use Class Based View, I would recommand you to use also a Base view if you want to check if user is logged in or not ([LoginRequiredMixin](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.contrib.auth.mixins/LoginRequiredMixin/))
- you gave a name to your url, so just use it instead of writing its raw form (that's what I did in my answer).