# SearchFilter: return .none() as long no ?search input given

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created the following view in my REST API. It works as intended, the only issue I still have is that if NO search term is defined, the first 15 results from my database are returned (without any filtering). Is there are a way to return `User.objects.none()` as long no `?search` input is given?

```
class UserRetrieve(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [RetoolPermissions]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ["email", "first_name", "last_name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview

> **queryset** - The queryset that should be used for returning objects from this view. Typically, you must either set this attribute, or **override the get_queryset() method**.

try this code below

```
class UserRetrieve(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [RetoolPermissions]
    # queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ["email", "first_name", "last_name"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Put your logic here ..

        term = self.request.GET.get('search')  # get the arg
        qs = super(UserRetrieve, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(name=term) if term else None
```

see this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21366037/12368419

Comment: Thanks for the help @cizario it seems like even when overwriting with get_queryset, `queryset =` still must be defined (so I removed the #). `qs.filter(name=term)` seems to filter only for one field. However, it must be a bit more complex lookup with `search_fields=["email", "first_name", "last_name"]`. Currently trying to figure out how to solve that now.

Comment: @JoeyCoder hi, did you find a solution ?

Comment: HI @cizario no, not yet.