# How to pass additional arguments to class view in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web

```
def edit_course(request,course_id):
    course=Courses.objects.get(id=course_id)
    return render(request,"hod_template/edit_course_template.html",{"course":course,"id":course_id})
```

The code above shows a view in django that is defined as a function. I want to recreate the same view as a class based view in django but I couldn't pass in an additional argument such as course_id into the class based view as it shows an error. Can someone tell me how to recreate that above function into a class based view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `DetailView` with `'course_id'` as `pk_url_kwarg`. An equivalent `DetailView` is:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class EditCourseView(DetailView):
    model = Courses
    pk_url_kwarg = 'course_id'
    context_object_name = 'course'
    template_name = 'hod_template/edit_course_template.html'
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Course` instead of <s>`Courses`</s>.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [URL-parameters and logic in django...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754122/url-parameters-and-logic-in-django-class-based-views-templateview/21366037)

You can access your `course_id` via

```
self.kwargs['course_id']
```

Use it inside class-based view functions